# How to animate background image size in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I am trying to make an animation of a background for a div.

I want it to look like the backgound image is being zoomed in to, like here:

http://www.teknologisk.dk/

For this purpose i want to be able to zoom in and out via jquery, something in the lines of this:

```
$('.DIVNAME').css("background-size:", "3000px auto");
```

I just need the correct code for this

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: your code is okay. if not working try this backgroundSize instead of background-size

Comment: @C-link thx for ur contribution. The answer was as suggested 'background-size', just forgot to remove the Colon (:)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the site you mentioned, you could use the  element instead of setting the image using CSS.

You can then set the image width 100%, and center it using javascript inside a parent container. The parent container will need to be set to width 100% as well, and javascript will detect the height of the $(window) and set the height of the parent container to that.

I'm assuming you don't care about IE8 and below, as you wanted to use background size, so you can now [CSS3 scale](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) to zoom in and out the images.